# How to solve USB debugging error when connecting my mobile with my laptop?

Tags: hardware

When I connect my mobile phone to my laptop, it is not recognised by Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the problem of software, just go to device manager option in system. Find the software related to USB , just update that software. After that just restart the android studio it will be fixed i hope so.